# Pesquisa Por Entidade com EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

Sou novo na no ramo e estou a das os meus primeiro passos.

Estou tentando criar um sistema de consolidação financeiro. Preciso que ele me retorne o total das despesas de uma determinada **Rubrica**.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Siscongest.Models
{
    public class Despesa
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdDespesa { get; set; }

        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione a Empresa")]
        [Display(Name = "Empresa")]
        public int IdEmpresa { get; set; }

        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione a Rubrica")]
        [Display(Name = "Rubrica")]
        public int IdRubricaDespesa { get; set; }       

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é requerido!!")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0 } recebe no máximo {1} caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é requerido!!")]
        [Display(Name = "Data da Despesa")]
        public DateTime DataDespesa { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é requerido!!")]
        [Display(Name = "Valor da Despesa")]
        public double Valor { get; set; }

        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione a Moeda")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é requerido!!")]
        [Display(Name = "Moeda")]
        public int IdMoeda { get; set; }

        public virtual Moeda Moeda { get; set; }
        public virtual RubricaDespesa RubricaDespesa { get; set; }
        public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Tenho a Lista completa das Despesas :**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var despesas = db.Despesas
                .Include(d => d.RubricaDespesa)
                .Include(d => d.Empresa)
                .Include(d => d.Moeda);
            return View(despesas.ToList());
        }
```

Preciso agora que ele me retorne a **Lista** com o Total por **Rubrica** , Total por **Empresas** e Total por **Moedas**.

Estou tentando utilizar o O código para o relatório mas não funciona

```
 public ActionResult GraficoDespesaRubrica(int? idRubrica)
            {
                var list = db.Despesas.OrderBy(d => d.DataDespesa)
                   .Where(d => d.IdRubricaDespesa == idRubrica);
                foreach(var rubri in list)
                {
                    list.Where(d => d.IdRubricaDespesa == idRubrica).
                        Sum(d => d.Valor);
                }
               var rubrica = new List<int>();
                var val = list.Select(x => x.Valor);
                var data = list.Select(x => x.RubricaDespesa.Descricao);

                var rub = rubrica;
                ViewBag.VALOR = val;
                ViewBag.Data = data;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem o seu modelo de dados todo e possíveis regras de negócio, penso que seja isto para o total de despesas de uma determinada **Rubrica**:

```
public double DespesaTotalPorRubrica(int idRubrica){
    var total = db.Despesas
        .Where(d => d.IdRubricaDespesa == idRubrica)
        .Sum(d => Valor);
    return total;
}
```

Por determinada **Empresa**:

```
public double DespesaTotalPorEmpresa(int idEmpresa){
    var total = db.Despesas
        .Where(d => d.IdEmpresa == idEmpresa)
        .Sum(d => Valor);
    return total;
}
```

Por determinada **Moeda**:

```
public double DespesaTotalPorMoedas(int idMoedas){
    var total = db.Despesas
        .Where(d => d.IdMoeda == idMoedas)
        .Sum(d => Valor);
    return total;
}
```

**O seu exemplo e comentários:**

```
public ActionResult GraficoDespesaRubrica(int ? idRubrica) 
{
    var list = db.Despesas.OrderBy(d => d.DataDespesa)
        .Where(d => d.IdRubricaDespesa == idRubrica); // Aqui tem todas as Despesas da Rubrica com o id igual a idRubrica
    foreach(var rubri in list) { //este foreach não irá fazer nada nem entendo o seu motivo, está a iterar cada Despesa em list, mas depois nem usa rubri e dentro do foreach está de novo a filtrar por id, não faz nenhum sentido.
        list.Where(d => d.IdRubricaDespesa == idRubrica).
        Sum(d => d.Valor);
    }

    var rubrica = new List < int > (); // Está a criar uma nova lista e depois não a usa para nada.
    var val = list.Select(x => x.Valor);
    var data = list.Select(x => x.RubricaDespesa.Descricao);

    var rub = rubrica; // Para que é esta variável?
    ViewBag.VALOR = val;
    ViewBag.Data = data;
}
```

Se está a indicar o id da Rubrica então só irá aparecer um valor que é a soma de todas as despesas correspondentes a essa **Rubrica**.

Para um gráfico precisa de vários valores.
Também não faz sentido ter uma data se são várias despesas então tem várias datas.

**O seu exemplo escrito de forma correta:**

```
public ActionResult GraficoDespesaRubrica(int? idRubrica)
{
    var total = DespesaTotalPorRubrica(idRubrica);

    ViewBag.VALOR = total;
}
```

**Valores das Despesas por Rubrica:**

```
db.Despesas
  .Include(d => d.RubricaDespesa) //incluir as Rubricas
  .Include(d => d.Moeda)          //incluir as Moedas
  .GroupBy(                       
    d => d.IdRubricaDespesa,      //agrupar as despesas por id da Rubrica
    (id, ld) => new {             //id's das Rubricas e lista de Despesas por id
      DescricaoRubrica = ld.First().RubricaDespesa.Descricao, //Descricao da primeira Rubrica, todas as Rubricas devem ter a mesma descricao porque são a mesma Rubrica
      ValorTotal = ld.Sum(d => d.Valor) //Soma de todos os valores das Despesas
      Moedas = ld.Select(d => d.Moeda) //Lista de Moedas das Despesas da Rubrica, cada Despesa pode ter uma Moeda diferente e por isso cada Rubrica também
    })
```

**Valores das Despesas por Empresa:**

```
db.Despesas
  .Include(d => d.Empresa)        //incluir as Empresas
  .Include(d => d.Moeda)          //incluir as Moedas
  .GroupBy(                       
    d => d.IdEmpresa,             //agrupar as despesas por id da Empresa
    (id, ld) => new {             //id's das empresas e lista de Despesas por id
      NomeEmpresa = ld.First().Empresa.Nome, //Descricao da primeira Empresa, todas as Empresas devem ter o mesmo nome porque são a mesma Empresa
      ValorTotal = ld.Sum(d => d.Valor) //Soma de todos os valores das Despesas
      Moedas = ld.Select(d => d.Moeda) //Lista de Moedas das Despesas da Empresa, cada Despesa pode ter uma Moeda diferente e por isso cada Empresa também
    })
```

Comment: Tentei e nãp funcionou

Comment: O que não funcionou? Você pediu imensas coisas e eu pedi que me indicasse o formato da lista final.

Comment: Queria uma listagem normal, ou então que retornasse em forma de grafico

Comment: Qual é o formato da lista? que objetos tem? Se você quer totais por cada entidade quer indicação dos id's em conjunto com os totais?

Comment: Quero uma lista com Totais por Rubricas, Totais por Empresa e por Moedas

Comment: MauroAlmeida Confirmou?

Comment: Alguem que me possa Ajudar?

Comment: "Quero uma lista com Totais por Rubricas, Totais por Empresa e por Moedas" - Isto não explica como quer objetivamente os dados, tem de dar um exemplo concreto do formato do  resultado final.

Comment: Qureria Algo Assim

Comment: queria uma listagem onde tivesse a soma de todas a Rubricas, 
Descrição da Rubrica - Valor Total - Moeda

queria uma listagem onde tivesse a soma de todas a Empresas, 
Nome da Empresa - Valor Total - Moeda

Comment: Será que voce poderia me ajudar Remotamente?

Comment: Alguem pode me dar uma ajudinha?

Comment: Manuel, veja se isso é o que quer, não sei o seu Modelo para as Rubricas e para as Empresas, mas pelo que pediu calculei que a **Rubrica** tivesse um campo **Descricao** e a **Empresa** um campo **Nome**. Se as minhas respostas o ajudaram a aprender e a resolver o seu problema, ou parte dele, coloque a resposta como aceite.

Comment: Agora estou a Receber esse erro " The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[System.String,System.Double]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Siscongest.Models.Despesa]'. "

Comment: em que linha de código?

Comment: quando chamo - http://localhost:54990/Despesas/DespesaPorEmpresa.
será que poderia me ajudar remotamente?

Comment: Tentei varias formas e não consegui. não sei como poderia ajudar-me

Answer (score -1):

O seu exemplo escrito de forma correta:

```
public ActionResult GraficoDespesaRubrica(int? idRubrica)
{
    var total = DespesaTotalPorRubrica(idRubrica);

    ViewBag.VALOR = total;
}
```

com Relação essa seu codigo! 
eu preciso que o grafico me mostre a total das despesas mensais, queria que fosse um para as Rubricas e um para as Empresas.
e relamente eu queria ver todas as rubricas se calhar não deva usar o int? idRubrica, se me poder ajudar, como disse sou junior e estou a começar a dar os meus primeiros passos

Answer (score -1):

esse é o erro que aparece quando tento chamar a pagina - http://localhost:54990/Despesas/DespesaPorEmpresa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não está a corresponder a View com os dados retornados do servidor, não está a dar binding certo. Por favor não coloque respostas para acrescentar algo à sua pergunta, edite a pergunta. A sua pergunta inicial já foi respondida de acordo com o pedido, devia assinalar como correta. Estas são outras questões e não é assim que o StackOverflow funciona.

Comment: Não indicou o tipo de objeto que a View está preparada para receber e saber mapear para HTML. Não consigo inferir isso a partir do Servidor nem das suas respostas, tem de ser específico no que pede.

Comment: A sua View está à espera de IEnumerable<Despesas> como indica no erro. Mas O que você pediu não foi esse objeto. Você pediu um agrupador de Totais por Empresa e por Rubricas e foi isso o devolvido. Tem de modificar a sua View de acordo com o objeto retornado do Servidor.

Comment: e como resolvo esse questão da view

Comment: Muda a View para a que quer. Aceite a resposta que dei e crie outra pergunta com a parte da View para poder ajudar nisso também.